# Deriving pdf of $U=logX$, where $X$ has pdf $f_X(x) = e^{-x}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

For the distribution $X$ with pdf $f_X(x) = e^{-x}$, I am trying to work out the pdf of $U = log X$.

Eventually, I got $f_U(u) = e^{-x}e^u$. I think from here I have to substitute the x out so my answer is in terms of u, is that correct? So that would give me pdf $$e^{u-e^u}$$?

Do you agree with this answer?

EDIT; Also, if the range of X is $x>0$, how can I use that information to work out the range of U?

Comment: The range or support of $U$ should be easy, since logarithm is a continuous increasing function.  What is the logarithm of a very small positive number?  What is the logarithm of a very large positive number?

Comment: @Henry Thanks. Does U have a range of $-\infty<u<\infty$?

Comment: Indeed it does.